# Drupal Display Suite Custom View Modes stopped appearing

Tags: view, drupal-7, mode, suite

I have recently noticed something odd with Display Suite. I am rather new to Drupal so if its something on my mistake please do not make fun of me.

But I have noticed that no new custom display settings (view nodes are being added to either node or field collection) previously it worked perfectly but now if I create a new view mode and attaching it to the node / field collection it seems it does not apply to it.

See the photos attached. Any suggestion?

http://oi59.tinypic.com/727fqp.jpg

http://oi59.tinypic.com/jb44cj.jpg

P.S. I have cleared drupal cache but it still keeps not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fist I'd say that if you're a new user to Drupal, using Display Suite is really jumping into the deep end. It's a really powerful module and creating View Modes is just the tip of the iceberg of what it can do. Second, when you create a new View *Mode*, you're doing it for an Entity (such as Content Types, Users, Comments, File - but not so much a single node, nor a field). You can find more info on what View Modes and entities are [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752). You don't need Display Suite to activate other View Modes but if all you're wanting to do is create a custom view mode, the lightweight module to use for that is [Entity View Mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode). Lullabot does a nice job of explaining this module [here](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/module-monday-entity-view-modes).

Anyhow, modules aside, note that the controls for turning View Modes on and off are only found on the 'Default' view mode for a given content type, ie: when on the Manage Display page of whatever content type you're working with, at the top right under the main tabs, you'll see your activated view modes. If you select 'Default' then you will see the control to turn on/off other view modes.

Now, maybe you're wondering how do you see what a particular View Mode looks. To do this, you're best off using Views as it ties in nicely with View Modes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cheers only now saw your response. Already solved this issue almost the same way you suggested....